# How do I include ttf custom font into my Rails app?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts

[I tried following this thread here but I am not able to duplicate their results.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228843/how-to-link-ttf-font-from-css-in-rails)

**main.css**

```
h1 {
  font-family: 'Shadows Into Light', serif;
  src: url('/assets/fonts/shadows.ttf') format("Shadows Into Light");
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 20px; 
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  width:100px;
}
```

**Assets Directories**

```
assets
|
|
---stylesheets
|  |
|   ---main.css
---images
|
|
---images
| 
|
---fonts
   |
    ---shadow.ttf
```

Additionally, I attempted to manually include the fonts directory into my asset pipeline:

**config/application.rb**

```
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
```

How do I include ttf custom font into my Rails app?

Answer (score 0):

```
@font-face  {
  font-family: 'yourfont';
  src: url('addres-yourfont.eot?#') format('eot'),  /* IE6–8 */
       url('addres-yourfont.woff') format('woff'),  /* FF3.6+, IE9, Chrome6+, Saf5.1+*/
       url('addres-yourfont.ttf') format('truetype');  /* Saf3—5, Chrome4+, FF3.5, Opera 10+ */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to use the asset pipeline at all. Just use [google fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts) and include the provided url in your **layouts.html.erb**. However, when you include the link to the font make sure you indicate the src as https and not http. In other words, instead of:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shadows+Into+Light">
```

use

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shadows+Into+Light">
```

The latter is being requested over https instead of http. You cannot request assets over non-secure protocols using Heroku.